# How can I allow opt-in subscription to specific groups with Webform CiviCRM?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

I'd like to provide the option for users to subscribe to one of two CiviCRM Mailing List groups when submitting a Webform.

From the [CiviCRM docs](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration#WebformCiviCRMIntegration-GroupsandTags) I can see how to use a CiviCRM-integrated Webform to add contacts to specific groups when they submit the form OR allow users to select from *any* of the groups in CiviCRM via the "User Select" option.

Is there a way to allow users to opt-in to a limited selection of existing groups, rather than allowing all groups?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have selected 'user select' for the groups in the CiviCRM section of the webform admin section, save and return to the 'components' tab (where all the webform fields are listed).  Find your Groups field and edit it from the component list. If you change the list from Live to Static, you can then select which of your groups will appear as an option to the user.

Comment: Right. Bonus points if you [update the docs](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration#WebformCiviCRMIntegration-GroupsandTags) :)

Comment: Docs updated :).